# Copy data from shared_ptr to struct

Tags: c++, memcpy, ros2

I've a setup where I need to exchange data provided in structs between two modules .

*Module 1* provides data in a shared_ptr of a struct, while *module 2* needs data in a "normal" struct.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cstring>

struct MyStruct1 {
 int x;
 double y;
 long long z;
};

struct MyStruct2 {
 int x;
 double y;
 long long z;
};

int main() {

  auto one = std::shared_ptr<MyStruct1>(new MyStruct1());

  MyStruct2 two;

  one->x = 10;
  one->y = 3.141;
  one->z = 1e9;

  std::cout << "Size of one: " << sizeof(one) << "\n";    // Size of one: 16
  std::cout << "Size of *one: " << sizeof(*one) << "\n";  // Size of *one: 24
  std::cout << "Size of two: " << sizeof(two) << "\n";    // Size of two: 24

  memcpy(&two, &(*one), sizeof(two));

  std::cout << "two.x: " << two.x << "\n";  // two.x: 10
  std::cout << "two.y: " << two.y << "\n";  // two.y: 3.141
  std::cout << "two.z: " << two.z << "\n";  // two.z: 1000000000

  return 0;
}
```

My project setup guarantees that both structs are defined exactly the same. Therefore, I make use of `memcpy`.

Since *one* is a (shared) pointer I tried to use it directly in the command

```
memcpy(&two, one, sizeof(two));
```

which results in the error `no suitable conversion function from std::shared_ptr<MyStruct1>" to "const void *" exists`.

As you see, I circumvent this by de-referincing and then making a normal pointer.
While this seems to work, it looks like a hard misuse.

Therefore, I'd kindly ask for your advice on how to copy data properly in this setup.

- Is there a better way than memcpy?
- How to address source and target properly?
- What needs to be considered in terms of efficiency (speed, memory usage)?

This is a simplified example. In real application, module 1 is a ros2 message callback, which has an interface like  `void topic_callback(const pck::msg::msg1::SharedPtr msg) const`
Additionally, the structs in my real application are nested with huge number of elements.
I do have an assertion, which double-checks that size of source and target are actually the same

Comment: `memcpy(&two, one.get(), sizeof(two));`

Comment: @amw actually, for the example, since the members are same so could it be possible to instantiate two objects form myStruct1 instead two different types. So you can use assignment operator for the object.

Comment: I doubt memcpy will be faster than a series of simple member assignments. I'd expect a compiler to produce the same code in both cases. Assignments have the advantage of being clear.

Comment: On second thought, I would not expect a compiler to produce the same code, I would expect it to produce better code for assignments (not necessarily just for the actual copying) precisely because the intent is clearer.

Comment: Use same type and assignment operator. `struct` is not magic word, it is **possible** to accidentally make non-trivially copyable `struct` that can't be copied by `memcpy` without UB.

Comment: @Nazim Both structs are defined from different external modules, I only exchange data. In fact, they are slightly different as mentioned above (ros message struct vs. struct out of a code generator)

Comment: @sklott What does UB mean?

Comment: Assignment would mean that I've to generate somehow more than 300 assignments and keep them up to date. That's the reason why memcopy with some process to ensure same data is preferred so far.

Comment: Why are there more than 300 members in one struct?! Also how do you know all members are ordered in exactly the same way in both structs? UB = Undefined Behavior

Comment: We mean to assign struct as a whole, not per element. If you can use same type, then just use `two = *one;`. And since one of definitions is generated from some external data I don't undetstand why you can't use this definition in other header. This seems to me as good way to mess up when one representation will differ from other, since they even written in different formats.

Comment: @sklott you are right but it needs an assignment operator overloading in the assigned type of the expression.

Comment: No. If you will use same type, which you should, then you DON"T need to overload assignment operator. On contrary, if you DO overload assignment operator your type will become non-trivially copyable,  and its copy process can't be as simple as `memcpy`. Look at this example: https://godbolt.org/z/56W4asbWx and check how compiler compiles line `MyStruct1 two = one_ref;`. I specifically added ref here so its clear what compiler generates only for this line. Trying to play with structure size, you can see how compiler uses different techniques for different data sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using same type for different objects assignment operator overloading can also copy content from one object to the other. I know you are trying to copy different types, maybe operator overloading for each type can be beneficial. By the way be aware of precision lost by copying elements for example first element of MyStruct1 can be float and the second type maybe integer.

Actually, my considiration here is copying obejcts of two different types can be tedious and error prone in the future even if size of two types are same.

After an update, here the solution i found. With this way you also check the types of other members.

```
struct MyStruct1 {
     int x;
     double y;
     long long z;

     MyStruct1& operator=(const MyStruct2& a) {
        x = a.x;
        y = a.y;
        z = a.z;
       return *this;
     }
  };
```

Note: :Since second type should be treated first it should be located above the first data type like:

```
struct MyStruct2 {
   float x;
   double y;
   long long z;
};

struct MyStruct1 {
   float x;
   double y;
   long long z;

   MyStruct1& operator=(const MyStruct2& a)
   {
      x = a.x;
      y = a.y;
      z = a.z;

      return *this;
   }
};
```

And the usage of the assignment look as simple as like that in the main:

```
two = *one;
```

instead of this

```
memcpy(&two, &(*one), sizeof(two));
```